# Authenticate with Firebase Anonymously

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am currently trying to let users achieve read access my Firestore database with anonymous authentication.

The reason I want to do this is because I keep getting emails saying "Your Cloud Firestore database has insecure rules" and I do not want to have the user to sign in.

To combat this problem I am making everyone an anonymous user when the application opens but I am having trouble with writing the rules that approve read access to anonymous users.

The function below is working:

```
func signInUser(){
    let auth = Auth.auth()

    auth.signInAnonymously{(result, err) in
        if let err = err{
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        print("User Logged in anonymously")
    }
}
```

How can I write a rule on the firebase console to allow read access only to the Firestore collections.

Also is this a bad idea?

Current Rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{document=**} {
  
      allow read: if true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest reading the [documentation on security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/insecure-rules#access_for_any_authenticated_user) to understand how user authentication works with security rules.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Whether or not this is a good idea is entirely up to you.  You'll have to decide if you want all users to be able to read all data.